# Core files in Thunderbird profile folder to backup

Tags: email, backup, thunderbird

I am using Mozilla Thunderbird in Windows to work solely with emails. I am backing up my Thunderbird profile folder containing all emails to my USB flash drive everyday. As I see from the backup log, many temporary files are copied to the flash drive during every backup - such as the files form the `cache2` and `shader-cache` folders. I think there is no need to back up those helper files. Can anybody tell me - what files/folders in a Thunderbird profile folder can be omitted from the backup to minimize its size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem myself. All emails are stored in the mail files inside the Mail subfolder of the Thunderbird profile. All what we need to back up is those files.

In Thunderbird, we can specify a custom location for mail files. This is done in Account Settings\Server Settings, in the Local Directory field. I just moved the original mail folder to another place to backup with all other files - that's all.

Restoring the mail folder in case of disaster is also very simple. We just need to change the mail folder location in a new Thunderbird profile and point to the folder with the restored mail files.